# Can a language support something like "Retry/Fix"?

Tags: programming-languages

I was just wondering if a language could support something like a Retry/Fix block?

The answer to this question is probably the reason it's a bad idea or equivalent to something else, but the idea keeps popping into my head.

```
void F()
{
  try
  {
    G();
  }
  fix(WrongNumber wn, out int x)
  { 
    x = 1;
  }
}

void G()
{
  int x = 0;
  retry<int>
  {
    if(x != 1) throw new WrongNumber(x);
  }
}
```

After the fix block ran, the retry block would run again...

Comment: How would that be different from a `catch` block?

Comment: because after the fix block the retry block would run again? that's what i was thinking at least.

Comment: We [already have it](http://docs.eiffel.com/book/platform-specifics/exception-mechanism#The_Rescue_Clause), it's named Eiffel. I do remember a similar clause in a yet another language which name I cannot recollect now.

Comment: Yet another obscure control structure a lisp hacker can implement with `call/cc` and a thirty line macro... that is, if they didn't already do it.

Comment: @9000, thanks for the link, that's very cool

Comment: I tried to fix the title to make it less not constructive but I still think it is soliciting debate. *This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

Comment: I don't understand, why this can't be implemented with simple `if else`. Why does it has to be implemented with new keyword?

Comment: Even Visual Basic has it: `On Error Goto X / Resume Next`

Comment: @crucifiedsoul: Because this involves multiple levels of the call stack. A single level of the call stack may not have all the context necessary to fully resolve an exceptional situation. Detecting an error often requires low level details which a high level function lacks, while selecting an appropriate response to an error often requires application specific logic which a low level function should not include -- therefore, the low level function must be able to communicate the exceptional situation up the stack (and possibly continue execution after the error is resolved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a language could do that.

There are examples in existing languages. Common Lisp provides a system which allows an exception (condition, in CL terminology) handler to return control to the point at which the exception was thrown, passing extra information about how the condition should be handled.

A good description of this is available in the book Practical Common Lisp, [19. Beyond Exception Handling: Conditions and Restarts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html)

As other commenters have mentioned, Scheme's general [continuation system](http://community.schemewiki.org/?call-with-current-continuation) could be used to implement this, and Eiffel [provides similar functionality](http://docs.eiffel.com/book/platform-specifics/exception-mechanism#The_Rescue_Clause).

*Thanks to @9000 and @delnan for bringing up Eiffel and call/cc in the comments on the question*